# Understanding the Local Polynomial Regression

Tags: r, regression

Could someone explain me why I get different lines when I plot? Somehow I thought the line should be the same

```
    data(aircraft)
    help(aircraft)
    attach(aircraft)

    lgWeight <- log(Weight)


    library(KernSmooth)

    # a) Fit a nonparametric regression to data (xi,yi) and save the estimated values mˆ (xi).

    # Regression of degree 2 polynomial of lgWeight against Yr
    op <- par(mfrow=c(2,1))
    lpr1 <- locpoly(Yr,lgWeight, bandwidth=7, degree = 2, gridsize = length(Yr))
    plot(Yr,lgWeight,col="grey", ylab="Log(Weight)", xlab = "Year")
    lines(lpr1,lwd=2, col="blue")
    lines(lpr1$y, col="black")
```

[image]

How can I get the values from the model? If I print the model, it gives me the values on `$x` and `$y`, but somehow if I plot them, is not the same as the blue line. I need the values of the fitted model (blue) for every `x`, could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fitted model (blue curve) is correctly in `lpr1`. As you said, the correct y-values are in `lpr1$y` and the correct x-values are in `lpr1$x`.

The reason the second plot looks like a straight line is because you are only giving the `plot` function one variable, `lpr1$y`. Since you don't specify the x-coordinates, R will automatically plot them along an index, from 1 to the length of the y variable.

The following are two explicit and equivalent ways to plot the curve and line:

```
lines(x = lpr1$x, y = lpr1$y,lwd=2, col="blue")  # plots curve
lines(x = 1:length(lpr1$y), y = lpr1$y, col="black")  # plot line
```